# Program to fill a matrix with 1s and 0s to such that it satisfies the given row and column sums

Tags: arrays, c

I am supposed to write a program which fills a matrix (`flag[][]`, here) with 0s and 1s such that the the given row and column sums are satisfied. The row and column sums are to be calculated by adding the fractional part of the elements of `a[][]`. I wrote the code given below, which works when I run just this part of it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    
int main()
{int m=3;
 int flag[3][3];
 int rSum[] = {1,1,2};
 int cSum[] = {2,1,1};
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{int k = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<rSum[i];j++)
    {
        if(cSum[k] == 0)
        {
            j--;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {  
            flag[i][k] = 1;
            cSum[k]--;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

But the whole code gives wrong output on running.
The whole code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 int main()
{
printf("Enter the size of matrix: ");
int m,n;
scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
float a[m][n];

printf("Enter the elements: ");
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);
    }
}

float b[m][n];
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        b[i][j] = a[i][j] - (int)a[i][j];
        printf("%f ",b[i][j]);  
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n\n\n");
float rSum[m], cSum[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cSum[i] = 0;
}
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    rSum[i] = 0;
}

for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        rSum[i] += b[i][j];
    }

}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        cSum[i] += b[j][i];
    }

}
printf("\nrSum:");
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    printf("%f ",rSum[i]);
}
printf("\ncSum:");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%f ",cSum[i]);
}
    
int flag[m][n];

for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        flag[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{int k = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<rSum[i];j++)
    {
        if(cSum[k] == 0)
        {
            
            j--;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {    
            flag[i][k] = 1;
            cSum[k]--;
            k++;
        }
    }
}   
printf("\n\n\n");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",flag[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake I am making? Why is the first code working fine, but not the second one?
Also, my input for `a[][]` was `{1.2 , 3.4, 2.4, 3.9, 4.0, 2.1, 7.9, 5.6, 0.5}`.

Comment: What do you expect to find? I run your code and it gives the correct answer (I think). Isn't it what you aim to find?: `1 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 1 1`

Comment: Yes! That is the output I expected.  But on running I was getting `1 1 0;  1 0 0;  1 1 0`. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: How did you print them? Add these lines at the end of your program.   `int i,j; for(i=0;i<3;i++){for(j=0;j<3;j++){printf("%d ",flag[i][j]);}printf("\n");}`

Comment: This code is actually a part of program where I also calculate the row sum and column sum, which are also coming to be `1 1 2` and `2 1 1` . I am editing the question to include the whole code as well

Comment: `b[i][j] = a[i][j] - (int)a[i][j];` fails when `a[i][j]` much outside `int` range.  Research `fmodf()`.

Comment: Instead of  `if(cSum[k] == 0)` --> try `if(fabsf(cSum[k] < 0.05f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you have one big mistake that is repeatedly  made in many parts: Do not behave `float` type variables as if they are `int`.

First of all, you shouldn't compare (`==`) a `float` number with any number. So `cSum[k] == 0` is wrong. Instead, you should specify a threshold and compare distance between the number and the threshold.

So change this line

```
if(cSum[k] == 0)
```

with

```
if (fabsf(cSum[k]) < epsilon) // You can set epsilon to 0.0005
```

where `epsilon` is a very small number (that is `float` type) that can be used as threshold.

Also, `cSum[k] -= 1.0f;` is much better than `cSum[k]--;` It is not necessarily wrong but you should tell `cSum[k]` is a `float` number to a person who reads your code.

Lastly, change this line

```
for(int j=0;j<rSum[i];j++)
```

with

```
for(int j=0;j<round(rSum[i]);j++)
```

I'll give you an example. Suppose

```
j = 2  rSum[i] = 2.00000000000000009
```

What can you say about `j < rSum[i]`?

In fact, we want them to be equal to each other but due to the precision issue in floating numbers they are not equal. Checking `j < rSum[i]` concludes that `rSum[i]` is greater than `j`. But it is wrong. So we should force them to be equal. For this reason, you can use `round` function to prevent this situation. You will get

```
j = 2  rSum[i] = 2.00000000000000000
```

You can find further information [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

In brief, in your program, since the comparison did not succeed, required `if` and `for` sections are passed.

Only change this part and add (`#include <math.h>`):

```
float epsilon = 0.0005f;
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{int k = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<round(rSum[i]);j++)
    {
        if(fabsf(cSum[k]) <epsilon)
        {
            j--;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            flag[i][k] = 1;
            cSum[k] -= 1.0f;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

After, you will find the output as you expected:

```
1 0 0 
1 0 0
0 1 1
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I used `for(int j=0;j<(int)rSum[i];j++)`  instead of  `for(int j=0;j<round(rSum[i]);j++)` as you said. But this is producing discrepancy in the output. Why is this happening? Isn't typecasting to `int` supposed to drop the fractional part, essentially doing exactly what `round()` is doing here?

Comment: For `float x = 1.999999999997;` `int(x)` will be `1` whereas `round(x)` will be `2`. `int(x)` gets rid of fractional part. `round(x)` rounds the number to the closest integer. Consider which function is useful for your program.

Comment: After all, if you want to use `int(x)`, you can use `int(x + epsilon)` because the number is now greater than `2`.

Comment: Further, we only talked about `<` and `non-negative` numbers. What about `negative` numbers and `>`. Then you have to take into account these cases.

Answer (score 0):

### The problems

First off, I don't see where you are setting your matrix to 0. If you are already receiving a matrix where every number is 0, please specify so.

But I also think that your logic in general can't resolve the given problem. You are using a greedy strategy that puts a number, whenever it is currently possible. But you have no guarantee that this is correct for the final solution.

### Example

Let's say you have the following matrix:

```
1 0 0 - 1  
0 0 1 - 1  
1 0 1 - 2  
| | |  
2 0 2
```

As you can see, the sums of rows are {1, 1, 2} and the sums of columns are {2, 0, 2}. Now your algorithm is going to correctly place the 1 in `flag[0][0]` then, as the row is completed, it is going to move to the next row.
Here it is going to place a 1 in the first column (`flag[1][0]`), as the column sum still allows for it and so does the row sum. Now again we move to the next row, having completed the second sum of rows.
The first column is already full, so we leave it with 0. The next column can't have anything but 0s, as its sum is 0. So we are only left with the 3rd column, where we put a 1. But now our final matrix `flag` looks like this:

```
1 0 0  
1 0 0  
0 0 1
```

Which is clearly a wrong answer.

### Possible solution

I would recommend trying to solve this problem using backtracking.

Comment: The author of the question has already found the correct answer. Please read the comment section of the question.

Comment: And you misunderstood the question. Initial matrix can be counted as a zero-matrix and some zeros will be changed as one. So there wouldn' t be any given matrix.

Comment: As you can clearly see, the given algorithm does not produce the correct result for every variation of the problem. Just run the example I gave. Also the question states "fills a matrix (flag[][], here) with 0s" and last time I checked, C does not initialize variables to 0. So in the code he gave the positions that are not set to 1 may have any arbitrary number. If the initial matrix can be counted as a zero-matrix, it should be stated in the question.

Comment: _C does not initialize variables to 0_ It is not true. C initializes unassigned variables in the global scope to 0. Test it after declaration by `printf("%d",flag[0][0]);`